# Scrapping Table from Website with Pandas Returning Empty Data Frame

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract 'Holdings' table from
https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf

I use pandas but it return me empty dataframe with only columns name.
Could anyone help me with this please?

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf'
tab = pd.read_html(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(tab[6])
```

Comment: The table is generated dynamically by JS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.